# return all @articles, except the first

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have @articles in my database and I want to query it but filter out the most recent article, then return all of the rest.

my controller is:

```
@articles = Article.find(:all, :order => "id desc")
```

and I am running a loop in my view:

```
<% @articles.each do |article| %>
...
<% end %>
```

I am imagining the view might be where I should apply some sort of filter, but can't seem to find any documentation in my search so far.

hopefully an easy one?

thanks for your help!
s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
@articles = Article.find(:all, :order => "id desc", :conditions=>["id !=?", Article.last])
```

Comment: This solution won't work if there are no Articles. Then it will raise a `RuntimeError: Called id for nil, which would mistakenly be 4`, since there would be no `Article.last`.

Comment: Ya I agree.Removed id as active record object solves this problem.

Answer (score 6):

This should solve your problem:

```
@articles = Article.order("id desc").offset(1).all
```